Acceleration of the nucleus
In the Bohr model of the atom, we traditionally take the nucleus to be at rest. However we know that it is not the case by Newton's 3rd law. So the nucleus and the electron must be revolving around their common center of mass. That means that the nucleus also must be accelerating. That implies that the positively charged nucleus must be emitting radiation by the Larmor formula. Then why is the atom stable? Bohr explained the stability of the electron by fixing it to rotate in stationary states where it did not emit radiation. SO does there exist stationary states for the nucleus too in the Bohr Model?
PS: I know that the Bohr model is wrong and about the Born-Oppenheimer approximation. I am simply asking why physicists at that time did not raise this particular argument against the model. Can we explain this without the Schrödinger equation?

Neither the nucleus nor electrons are accelerating. They are both part of the same wave function, if you want to write the hydrogen problem in a formulation that actually obeys relativity and momentum conservation. If you do that, then you will find that the electronic part and the nuclear part of that wave function are forming an entangled pair. I have seen textbooks that calculate this "correctly" (could have been Sakurai, but I am not sure) but you need a  theorist to write it out for you, if somebody volunteers.

This question is similar to: Hydrogen Ground State Energy. The relevant concept is just to use the reduced mass formalism. There are recent theoretical progress; if you want to use the Dirac equation for the proton too, then there is now a new scheme that works better than before. It still does not have QED involved, but it is a much better starting point for finding QED corrections. The problem of "centre of mass position" is SR is still not solvable / solved, though.

I start with a story that is only tangentially related to your question, but worthwhile anyway, in my opinion.
The Bohr model was also applied to the case of single ionized Helium. Then there is not only the difference that the Helium nucleus has twice as much electric charge as the Hydrogen nucleus, the reduced mass comes out differently too.
Of course, the Bohr model was still quite far away from what eventually became quantum theory. But there is a lot of correspondence. So much so that by the 1920's Niels Bohr offered that as a principle: Bohr's correspondence principle: quantum mechanics must be constrained to be such that in the macroscopic limit the description coincides with classical mechanics.
There is an answer on the History of Science and Mathematics Stackexchange that goes into the story of the Bohr model and reduced mass

More generally, I assume that it is for the sake of simplicity that the electron energy levels are usually described as something that involves the electron only. Given the mass difference that simplification is sensible.
But as demonstrated by the Hydrogen and single ionized Helium spectra example, the energy levels are in actual fact energy levels of the nucleus-electron system.
A quantum jump in energy level is not a jump of the electron on its own, it's a jump of the nucleus-electron system.

You should have added this rather nice answer to the duplicate that I have found, rather than here.

@naturallyInconsistent Please give a link to that earlier question. If this question is indeed a duplicate I will move this answer. (Incidentally, this very same question was posted by the OP a day ago, and was very quickly deleted again by the OP. I was surprised to see it reposted.)

I marked it as duplicate and it is under the OP's question now, thanks to the automatic system giving that comment. But I think you can send it to another question that would have a better alignment with your answer than the one I picked. I particularly liked your HSM link. Always wonderful
